# Поиск в БД значений, которые соответствуют началу строки

Tags: sql, postgresql, поиск

**Задача:** PostgreSQL. У меня есть строка. А в базе данных много значений. Мне нужно достать из БД такие значения, которые полностью соответствуют началу строки.

**Приведу пример:**

У меня есть случайная строка `hg23yu76`, назову её string. А в базе есть такая таблица `values`:

```
id | value
---+----------
1  | hg2
---+----------
2  | hg23x
---+----------
3  | 3yu
---+----------
4  | hg23yu761
```

Запрос должен вернуть значение `hg2`, оно соответствует началу string. Остальные строки не подходят, потому что:

1. `hg23x` не соответствует началу string, т.к. в `hg23x` после `3` идёт `x`, а в string после `3` следует `y`
2. `3yu` соответствует середине string, мне нужно, чтобы соответствовало началу
3. `hg23yu761` не соответствует началу string, т.к. в string нету `1`. Проще говоря, строка в БД, которая длиньше string не подходит

   ```
   SELECT * FROM values WHERE ...
   ```

Как дописать этот запрос, чтобы он выполнял мою задачу?

Comment: Вообще-то нехорошо использовать в качестве имени таблицы зарезервированное слово.

Comment: @Akina это ненастоящая таблица, просто привёл пример, чтобы было проще

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM "values" 
WHERE 'hg23yu76' LIKE values.value || '%';
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=28e20a8e45cc477e72589c0dce7c70f2)

Comment: Спасибо, не могли бы уточнить, что означает выражение `values.value || '%'` и как оно работает?

Comment: `||` - это оператор строковой конкатенации. Т.е. к значению поля на хвост подклеивается символ процента, который при использовании в шаблоне оператора LIKE обозначает "любое количество любых символов".